# Silverlight synchronous calls to the wcf

Tags: wcf, silverlight

I'm trying to make calls sync. But silverlight app locks itself when calling endList method. In a simple console app i can make async to sync. Could not see the problem.

```
  var svc = new WcfServiceClient();
  var ar = svc.BeginList(null, null);
  var result = svc.EndList(ar); <-- Silverlight hangs here
  listBox.ItemsSource = result;
```

Answer (score 2):

Silverlight doesn't support Sync calls.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SynchronousSilverlight.aspx) is a article about synchronous calls to webservices and a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You can do that if you are not on the Dispatcher thread, something like:

```
System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state =>
    {
        IAsyncResult asyncResult = svc.BeginSomething(null, null);

        if (!asyncResult.CompletedSynchronously)
        {
            asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
        }

        try
        {
            svc.EndSomething(asyncResult);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.Close();
        }
    });
```

The big advantage of this is that you can keep your domain model layer synchronously like in the old days, you can implement lazy loading easily etc...

**But** in practice you can only use it when you design your application to strictly adhere to the **MVVM** / **Commanding** patterns, where your ViewModels and Commands handle the switching between the dispatcher thread and the model threads. It's a lot of ground work to do, and there are some gotchas, but when it works, it works wonderfully.

If you want to use ready-to-use framework that works similarly, it is available here: [CodeProject: Introducing the Model Thread View Thread Pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/Mtvt.aspx). The architecture is explained very well too on that page.