# WCF does not generate Begin/End methods, only MyMethodAsync version

Tags: wcf, asynchronous

As I tried to describe in the title, I don't get the Begin and End methods when I add my service reference. I do get the GetStudentsAsync() method, but I want to be able to await.

The interface is simple:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ISchoolLightService
{
    [OperationContract]
    ObservableCollection<SLUser> GetStudents();

    [OperationContract]
    ObservableCollection<SLUser> GetTeachers();
}
```

and GetStudents looks like:

```
public ObservableCollection<SLUser> GetStudents()
{

        var users = (from u in ent.Users
                     where u.UserType == "Student"
                     select new SLUser
                     {
                         UserID = u.UserID,
                         ...
                     });

        return new ObservableCollection<SLUser>(users);
    }
```

The client is a Silverlight 5 project, and the server is a .NET 4.5 class library. Shouldn't I get these methods?

Perhaps worth mentioning is that I have to untick the "Always generate message contracts" and "Reuse types in referenced assemblies" of it won't compile.

EDIT: Looking in the Object Browser, it seems the methods are there, but private! Why? How do I change this behavior?

EDIT2: It seems the better question is "How do I enable task-based operations in Silverlight projects?". This does not seem to be possible. The work-around I have found seems to be something along the lines of (with another data context):

```
    public static Task<ObservableCollection<Customer>> GetCustomers()
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<ObservableCollection<Customer>>();

        var client = new CustomerServiceClient();

        client.GetCustomersCompleted += (s,e) =>
            {
                if (e.Error != null)
                    tcs.TrySetException(e.Error);
                else if (e.Cancelled)
                    tcs.TrySetCanceled();
                else
                    tcs.TrySetResult(e.Result);
            };

        client.GetCustomersAsync();

        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

Is this indeed the (only) way to do it?

Comment: Did you specify the option to generate async when adding a service reference in VS? This is VS feature not WCF btw.

Comment: I have come a little further in my research now. This option seems to be greyed out in Silverlight applications for some reasons. That seems to be why I don't get the methods. Wondering if there is a way to force their generation.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thecrmguys/archive/2012/08/28/silverlight-async-with-visual-studio-2012.aspx)?

Comment: I'm unable to repro this. Adding a SL5 service reference to http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/searchservice/searchservice.svc gives me an `ISearchService` with public `BeginSearch` and `EndSearch` methods.

Comment: iirc SL doesn't support mode other than **async**. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648249/call-synchronous-wcf-operation-contract-methods-asynchronously-on-silverlight) and pthis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068266/silverlight-synchronous-calls-to-the-wcf).

Comment: @StephenCleary: But do you know if is has to do with that services implementation? Perhaps they have somehow explicitly implemented the begin/end versions?

Comment: @SamiHuutoniemi: When you create a proxy from a service reference, the implementation doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try using BeginInvoke

first define a delegate

```
public delegate ObservableCollection<SLUser> GetStudentsAsync();
```

and call the method

```
GetStudentsAsync del = new GetStudentsAsync(GetStudents);
del.BeginInvoke(params, callback, object); // use input parameters if needed/
```

Comment: What I want is to be able to do is something like:

var result = Task<...>.Factory.FromAsync(service.BeginGetStudents, service.EndGetStudents);